# Is there a way to narrow the search space of a CRC hash to identify the original message?

Tags: hash, collision-detection, collision, crc

I am looking for an efficient way to reduce the set of possible messages for a CRC hash, given an arbitrary hash value and known message size. Using brute force to calculate all possible collisions is not feasible for a large messageLength. Assume that the hash length is at least 100 times smaller than the messageLength (messageLength of 100K and hash size is 1K)

Example:

```
List<byte[]> ComputeCollisions(byte[] hash, int messageLength){
  var collisions = new List<byte[]>();
  //do some magic
  return collisions;
}
```

Given how simple the CRC hash function works, I tend to believe that there is some way to do it, similar to unzipping it backwards, I just cannot figure out how to do it.  To reduce the search space further would knowing the first or last XOR applied help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [spoof](https://github.com/madler/spoof). You can use it to modify messages to give you a desired CRC.

Comment: For a given set of spoof parameter (CRC, message length, bit locations), is there an alogrithm to predict the chances of finding a collision using spoof?

Comment: It depends only on the number of candidate bit locations to flip provided. (Assuming that the message is at least as long as the CRC.)

Comment: "It is important to offer more than a minimal set of bit locations for spoof to modify. For a k-bit CRC, the probability of no solution for a minimal set of k randomly selected locations is 71%.  However that probability drops rapidly as more locations are added.  It is 42% for k + 1 random locations, 23% for k + 2, 12% for k + 3, and it continues to drop by about a factor of two for each additional location.  For k + 10 randomly selected locations, the probability of no solution is 0.1%.  Interestingly, these probabilities are independent of the length of the CRC, for k from 8 to 64."

Comment: What's the equation behind those percentages? Also it says "...independent of the length of the CRC, for k from 8 to 64". What about <8 and >64?

Comment: The results are empirical, and I only tested them for a small set of common CRC lengths in the range of 8 to 64. I suspect that the results are the same for any length CRC. I also suspect that there is an easily derivable formula for those probabilities, but I haven't tried to derive it. Yet.

Comment: In spoof there seems to be only one "ref" parameter (including in and out) while Rock Soft model requires separate refin and refout parameters. So spoof doesn't fully support Rock Soft CRCs?

Comment: @Silicomancer Correct, spoof does not directly support a different refin and refout. However you can simply reverse the desired CRC bits manually to get the same effect. (Out of the 102 CRC definitions in Greg Cook's catalog, one of them has differing refin and refout parameters.)

Comment: I would like to find two messages that result in the same given CRC checksum. So I passed 0 as 'wanted' (which is checksum xored with itself) to crc_solve(). However it returns 0. I would like to force it to return either -1 or >= 1 (i.e. it shall find solutions only that require at least 1 bit flip). Is this possible with your code?

Comment: No, spoof doesn't do that. What you are looking for are codewords of the CRC, which are sets of bits that exclusive-or'ed into a message that does not change the CRC. You can use the CRC polynomial itself for that, but including the high bit (x^n where n is the length of the polynomial).

Comment: @Silicomancer So for example, the 16-bit CRC listed as `0x8005` is really the polynomial `0x18005`. If you flip those four bits with those distances from each other shifted anywhere in the message (in the proper order depending on reflection), it will leave the CRC unchanged.

Comment: You can do that multiple times, including trying to use the polynomial shifted to cancel parts of itself to try to get fewer bits flipped, e.g. a lower-weight codeword.

Comment: You can also search for the lowest-weight codewords for any given message length, which unfortunately requires a brute-force approach.

Comment: @Silicomancer I have added a program called "ruse" to the spoof repository that uses Philip Koopman's library of found codewords to modify a few bits in a file, leaving the CRC unchanged.